# How to hold bootstrap popover so that user can click on buttons in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a div. On its hover i show a popover. I have made two buttons in popover. 
Problem is when i take my mouse to press the button popover disappears. I making the divs dynamically. What i have tried is this:

```
$('.more').click(function() {
         opinionBox += '<div onmouseenter="test($(this))" class="opinion">hello</div>';
         $(this).append(opinionBox);
})
```

For popover:

```
function test(box) {
   box.popover({title: 'Current Opinion',
                trigger: 'hover', 
                html: 'true', 
                content: '<div><button>Press Me</button></div>', 
                placement: 'left'
              }).popover('show');
}
```

Comment: I think .popover('show') does not required. Show / hide will work as per your 'trigeer' attribute defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used 'hover' event, So when your mouse is out of div popover will be removed. If 'click' will work for you then you can use trigger event as 'click'. This will not remove div after your mouse out.

```
box.popover({title: 'Current Opinion',
            trigger: 'click',            // Changed event from hover to click
            html: 'true', 
            content: '<div><button>Press Me</button></div>', 
            placement: 'left'
          }).popover('show');
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to put **popover attribute 'delay'(in ms)**:

```
function test(box) {
   box.popover({title: 'Current Opinion',
                trigger: 'hover', 
                delay: { hide: 5000 },  // or greater time as you think 
                html: 'true', 
                content: '<div><button>Press Me</button></div>', 
                placement: 'left'
              }).popover('show');
}
```